# Create a full screen application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, pinvoke, windows-ce

We want our application to run in full screen mode with no title bar on a Win CE 5.0 powered device. The application is being developed using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (C#).

I have followed [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.FindWindowW) tutorial, but I encountered an error. Here is my code:

```
namespace DatalogicDeviceControl
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public const int SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
    public const int SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000;
    public const int SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020;
    public const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    public const int SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;
    public const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    public const int SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100;
    public const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    public const int SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200;
    public const int SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008;
    public const int SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200;
    public const int SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400;
    public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    public const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    public const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    public const int HWND_TOP = 0;
    public const int HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
    public const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    public const int HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HideStartBar();
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);


    public void HideStartBar()
    {
        IntPtr handle;

        try
        {
            // Find the handle to the Start Bar
            handle = FindWindowCE("HHTaskBar", null);

            // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // Hide the start bar
                SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not hide Start Bar.");
        }
    }

}
```

}

I have encountered the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'DatalogicDeviceControl.Form1.SetWindowPos(System.IntPtr, int, int, int, int, uint)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dzerow: Your answer is correct: Windows Mobile does not support the `user32.dll` library.

Use the `coredll.dll` library instead.

```
private const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;
private const string CORE_DLL = "coredll.dll";
private static IntPtr _taskBar;
private static IntPtr _sipButton;
private static string _deviceId, _deviceIp;
private static DateTime _lastUpdateCheck, _startTime;

[DllImport(CORE_DLL)]
public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, uint dwRop);

[DllImport(CORE_DLL)]
public static extern bool CeRunAppAtEvent(string appName, int Event);

[DllImport(CORE_DLL, EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport(CORE_DLL)]
private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport(CORE_DLL)]
public static extern bool MessageBeep(int uType);

[DllImport(CORE_DLL, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

Below is a lot of the code from an application I used to manage. Parts of it may be incomplete and there could be too much info. If something is missing, just comment and I will fill that in.

Basically, the routine I have written enables you to call `ShowWindowsMenu(bool enable)` to either enable or disable the **HHTaskBar** (task bar) and the **MS_SIPBUTTON** (soft input button).

```
public static void ShowWindowsMenu(bool enable) {
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) {
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _taskBar = FindWindowCE("HHTaskBar", null); // Find the handle to the Start Bar
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show Start" : "Hide Start", err);
  }
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _sipButton = FindWindowCE("MS_SIPBUTTON", "MS_SIPBUTTON");
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show SIP" : "Hide SIP", err);
  }
}
```

Be sure to turn these features back on when your program exits, or the user will have to reboot the device to get those re-enabled.

**EDIT:** I forgot the `WindowPosition` enumerated value I created:

```
public enum WindowPosition {
  SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
  SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
}
```

Sorry about that.

Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Windows Mobile doesn't contain `user32.dll`, as well as many other normal Windows API DLLs. I had to P/Invoke into `coredll.dll` instead. For signatures, see [PInvoke.net's](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/CreateProcess.html#) section (at the bottom left) for "Smart Device Functions".

Comment: +1. I've posted code below to use `coredll.dll` instead. Basically, it is the same - just replace the library reference.