# Dealing with user interface inside a thread (Compact-Framework)

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, windows-ce

We want to display a "Loading, please wait..." screen before the application starts executing other functions on a Win CE 5.0 powered device. The application is being developed using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (C#).

The issue is that, the UI is only updated once the set of current processes are completed,  to a stage where other functions will only run with user interaction. C# has a `Form.Shown()` event, which would allow the application to run other functions, only ONCE the form has been displayed. However, the Compact-Framework does **NOT** include.

The solution I've approached was using multi-threading, where I would have one thread which would display the "Loading, please wait..." screen, and the other would take care of other function.

The issue with Threading is, when managing UI components, it gives an error if not applied the correct techniques:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThreadStart tstart = new ThreadStart(showLoad);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tstart);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(checkConnect); 

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private void checkConnect()
    {

        conn.portConnect(); //Connects to port Successfully
        if (conn.isConnected == true) //Variable which checks the connectivity status
        {
            panelMENUshow(); 
        }
        else
        {
            panelCONFIGshow();
        }
    }

    private void showLoad()
    {
        if (imgLoading.InvokeRequired)
        {
            imgLoading.Invoke((Action)(() => imgLoading.Show())); //Image box displaying "Loading, please wait..." shows successfully if I use Control.Invoke
        }

        //If I don't use Control.Invoke I get the following error:
        //"Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread."
    }
```

On the `showLoad()` function, it is not a problem to add Control.Invoke. However, the functions `panelMENUshow()` and `panelCONFIGshow()` contains many bits of code that manages UI components, and it would be not practical to use Control.Invoke in every line of code referring to a UI component.

Is there a way of:

1. stopping the threading but carry on running the code that involves UI management?
2. practically manage UI components within a thread?

PS: The approach was based on the [answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911059/create-a-full-screen-application).

Answer (score 0):

Use the refresh function to force the control to be immediately redrawn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When writing WinForm apps you want to keep the complexities of threading away from the main UI thread.  I've seen too many applications with thread code weaving in and out of them, tying the logic into a knot.

Instead, model anything that requires any kind of threading as a component that, while it may use threads internally, presents a friendly, even-based model to the outside world.  These components should not have any direct interaction with your UI.

Given that, your code would look something more like this (just an example, not syntax checked and probably with lots of typos etc, but it will give you an idea):

```
public class CommunicationObject
{
    // you will probably have several EventArgs to define to pass extra info
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Connected;

    // you need this instance to dispatch events to the UI thread
    private Control _invoker;

    public CommunicationObject(Control invoker)
    {
       _invoker = invoker;

       // start a thread here, or better yet, add an Enabled property or
       //   Start method to kick it off
    }

    // from the thread that is doing the real work, call this when you are connected 
    private void OnConnected()
    {

        _invoker.Invoke(() => 
        { 

            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = Connected;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty); // eventually you might need your own event args
            }

        });

    }
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private CommunicationObject _comm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        imgLoading.Show(); // show msg until connected

        _comm = new CommunicationObject(this);

        _comm.Connected += Comm_Connected; // wire up event handler
    }

    private void Comm_Connected(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (imgLoading.Visible)
        {
            imgLoading.Hide(); // hide once connected
        }

        panelMENUshow(); 

    } 
}
```

Note that the form has no threads in it at all.  Push that complexity into stand-alone objects.  It might seem like a bit more work, but you will thank yourself later!